# How to count the amount of same results in column?

Tags: php, mysql, count

I've developed a database, where i have three sets of columns:
- Username
- Feeling
- Remark

The entry's for feelings are all the same, because they're being selected from a dropdown menu. I'm looking for a way to count the amount of same results and then echo it on a site with PHP, but I can't get any further than this:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password", "database");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM thefeels WHERE feeling = 'Happy'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

var_dump($result)
?>
```

In this code I want to count the amount of times happy occurs in a column, but even that is not working. How can I count the amount of times the same results is in a column?
So if Happy is there four times and Sad two times it should display:

```
Happy: 4
Sad: 2
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html

Comment: You need to use `SELECT feelting, COUNT(*) AS count .... GROUP BY feeling`  instead of WHERE clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic *Counting Rows* task. You will find some examples in the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html).

In your case it would be:

```
$query = "SELECT feeling, COUNT(*) as count FROM thefeels GROUP BY feeling";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

Now you can use the "old school" way (which you will find in many totorials):

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "{$row['feeling']}: {$row['count']}<br>";
}
```

or move forward and separate data fetching from data processing and data output with:

```
$feelingCounts = $con->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

And do what ever you need with the fetched data. For example:

```
var_dump($feelingCounts);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
 SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN feeling = 'Happy' THEN 1 END)  as Happy,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN feeling = 'Sad' THEN 1 END)  as Sad
 FROM thefeels
```

Comment: I've done it! What is best way now, to echo this with an php function on my website? Because as said in my question, when I echo it with my code, I'm not getting any results...

Comment: What? Why? It should be a basic `COUNT(*) .. GROUP BY` query.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel `GROUP BY`  return multiple rows, this give you the result in a single row.

Comment: For the PHP you should make a different question. But there is a lot of material on google to do that.